Escaping on backslash itself
The escaping on the backslash itself behaves weird in Redis. The context is that I need to index a document but want to avoid the impact on the backslash (escape separator) if the document contains the backslash.
1 I tried indexing on text "login\\ today". From my understanding, the text should be tokenized into two worlds "login\" and “today” because the escaping on the backslash itself the space will be as is and thus separate the words.
ft.create test_idx on hash prefix 1 “test:doc:” schema detail text hset test:doc:doc1 detail “login\\\\ today” # in CLI we need to double backslash

However, when I searched for “today”, it returns nothing.
ft.search test_idx “today”

If I searched for “login\\today”, the document was retrieved.
ft.search test_idx “login\\\\today”

I’m very confused and didn’t why.
2 I also found something else.
127.0.0.1:6379> ft.explaincli test_idx "login\\\\\\\\today"
1) UNION {
2)   login\today
3)   +login\today(expanded)
4) }

I though it should have searched for “login\today” but some of the middle backslashes are stripped.  I’m using redis_version:6.2.11 and search:2.6.7
I would appreciate if anyone can answer my questions.
Thank you so much.

Understanding the behavior of backslashes in Redis, especially within the context of indexing and searching in RediSearch, can indeed be tricky due to how backslashes are treated both in the input and during processing. Here’s a detailed breakdown to help clarify what’s happening in your scenario:
1. Indexing and Searching with Backslashes
Indexing "login\ today"
When you index the text "login\ today" using:
hset test:doc:doc1 detail "login\\ today"

The backslash () is a special character in many programming contexts, often used as an escape character. In Redis CLI and in many programming environments, you need to escape the backslash itself, which means you should write \ to represent a single .
However, it seems like you are correctly escaping the backslashes. The text should be tokenized into "login" and "today" if the space remains as is.
But due to how backslashes are processed, there are nuances to consider:

Storage in Redis: The text login\ today is stored as-is, but
internally it might be interpreted with escaping rules.
Tokenization: RediSearch might treat backslashes in a special way,
impacting how it    tokenizes the input.

Searching for "today"
When you search for "today":
ft.search test_idx "today"

It returns nothing because the tokenizer might not recognize "today" as a separate token if the backslash handling affects tokenization.
Searching for "login\today"
When you search for "login\today":
ft.search test_idx "login\\\\today"

This involves double escaping due to the Redis CLI parsing. Each backslash needs to be escaped, so \ becomes \\. The search retrieves the document because it matches the token as interpreted during indexing.
2. Explanation of the Query Parsing
When you run:
ft.explaincli test_idx "login\\\\\\\\today"

You see:
1) UNION {
2)   login\today
3)   +login\today(expanded)
4) }

This output indicates how the query is parsed and executed internally. Here's the breakdown:

Input Processing: The input string "login\\\\today" contains
eight backslashes. Each pair of backslashes \\ represents a single
\ in the search string.
Query Parsing: The RediSearch query parser interprets these
backslashes. In this case, \\ is interpreted as \ which further
reduces to . Thus, login\\\\today becomes login\today (four
backslashes become two due to double escaping).

Key Points to Remember

Escaping Backslashes: Always consider that backslashes need to be
escaped, and this doubling effect needs to be accounted for in both
indexing and searching.

Tokenization Nuances: The presence of backslashes can affect how text is tokenized. Ensure your understanding aligns with how RediSearch interprets these characters.

Query Interpretation: The explain command shows how the query is parsed and executed, shedding light on how backslashes are treated.




Indexing and Tokenization Rule

-Input: "login\\ today" (4 backslashes in CLI)
-Stored as: login\ today
-Tokenized into: login\ and today
Searching
-Search for today:
Should match, but if it doesn't, it suggests tokenization might be affected by the backslash.
-Search for login\today:
Query: ft.search test_idx "login\\today"
Should retrieve the document because the entire login\ today is treated as a single token.
Explanation with Multiple Backslashes
-Input: "login\\\\ today" (8 backslashes in CLI)
-Stored as: login\\ today
-Explain Query: ft.explaincli test_idx "login\\\\\\ today" (16 backslashes)
Shows login\ today, indicating multiple backslashes might be collapsed into fewer during parsing.
Key Points

Double Escape Backslashes: In CLI, every backslash needs to be doubled.

Tokenization: RediSearch may treat backslashes as part of tokens, impacting how spaces are recognized.

Query Parsing: Multiple backslashes can be collapsed, affecting search behavior.



Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Though I'm still confused.

Indexing and Searching with Backslashes
I actually want to know more about the rule of tokenization, especially the difference between query and indexing. Like for the example of "login\ today" (in cli there should be 4 backslashes), I thought it will be tokenized into two words "login" and "today", because the first two backslashes should be interpreted as the literal "" and thus the space will break it into two words. Theoretically, I should be able to search for "today".



I actually tried "login\\\\\\\\ today" in CLI (16 backslashes, result in 8 in text). However the explain returns "login\ today" (single backslashes). It seems that multiple literal backslashes are merged into. I tried 24 backlashes as well but it still returns just one in the explain. It's hard to figure out the reason.


An issue was created https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch/issues/4732
